# Finding the velocity of a ball thrown upwards

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, time, velocity, free-fall

A ball is thrown upwards with a speed of 16.1 m/s. What is the ball's velocity 1.6 seconds after it is released?

I tried to solve this using the equation: $v = u+at$, substituting u for 16.1, a for 9.8 and t for 1.6. I got an answer of 31.78 which is incorrect.

I dont think it should be faster than the initial velocity given that gravity is acting on the ball. Also I am not sure if I should use -9.8 m/s^2 as that yields an answer of 0.42.

What is wrong  with my approach? What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration is in the opposite direction from the initial velocity.  If you are measuring positive upwards (by taking the initial velocity to be $+16.1$) the acceleration of gravity is negative.  Your second answer is correct, but has one place too much accuracy as your data only goes to one place behind the decimal point.